# Display R code in Latex (with highlighted color)

Tags: r, code

[image]

How can I type  R syntax in Latex(with the color like green, blue, gray for text)? And also the symbol ```. Thank you

Comment: Look at the `listings` package.

Comment: @JPi Can you do some examples for me? I know this package but I could not use it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings What have you tried?

Comment: I don't use the package myself, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

After I try listings package based on some previous answers, it turns out like this @@